# how to read cookie.sqlite file in firefox through python program

Tags: python, sqlite, cookies

I tried to open and read the contents of cookie.sqlite file in the firefox.
cookie.sqlie is the database file were all cookies of webpages opened in firefox are stored. When I am trying to access with a python program it is not allowing to read, as cookie.sqlite is locked. How to open and read the contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a programming question as is -- sqlite sets a flag in the file so that when trying to open the file a second time, the other sqlite instance knows that the file is "dirty", because the first Sqlite is actively modifying it. There's no way around this -- data integrity is the core functionality of databases, and hence, you really shouldn't try to do that.

I'd generally recommend just writing a Firefox extension, which then can access the cookie database as accessible from within firefox, and export whatever you need to your external program.